# Software Raid0 doesn't mount successfully in fstab

Tags: boot, mount, raid, fstab, mdadm

I have created a Raid0 and it works as I expect it. The the array file is created at `/dev/md0`. I want this to be mounted automatically by adding this line at the end of the `/etc/fstab` file :

```
/dev/md0 /mnt/storage ext4 noatime,commit=60,data=writeback,nodiratime,journal_async_commit,nouser_xattr 0 0
```

and this Line at the end of the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=lil-RIKO:lil-RIKO UUID=6016d5e4:6e42cb97:6b2a8e6e:098c1982
```

In Boot time, I saw that /mnt/storage was being waited to be mounted and provide two options : to Skip ... or to Ma... I forgot what its says. I waited so long that made think something is wrong. I went into the "maintenance mode" which is a root shell then I quickly checked presence of `/dev/md0` file. The File wasn't there, only /dev/md127. I tried to mount that file instead and it complained about not finding a superblock. I manually mounted the raid via `mdadm --assemble /md0`after removing the `/dev/md127` file via `mdadm --stop /dev/md*`  and I continued booting. Next reboot, I experienced the same issue.

How come the raid wasn't get automatically mounted? There was no presence of /dev/md0 at boot time and I was able to mount it manually.

EDIT1: I have managed to "merge" it into one which is /dev/md127 by removing a disk , The problem still occurs but when I issue ths `cat /proc/mdstat` I got this:

```
md127 : inactive sdc[1](S) sdb[0](S)
      7830528 blocks super 1.2
```

This means (I think ) the raid is not yet activated. But when I reattached it it comes active like this:

```
md127 : active raid0 sdc1[1] sdb1[0]
      7830528 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

What went wrong this time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you already found an answer; if not, I just went through this, and the short answer is to edit your array definitions at /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf; basically remove anything other than the /dev/md* and UUID= info (delete metadata, name, etc).  On reboot, you should no longer have the md127, md126, etc problem with your arrays.

So based on your line above, change

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=lil-RIKO:lil-RIKO UUID=6016d5e4:6e42cb97:6b2a8e6e
```

to

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=6016d5e4:6e42cb97:6b2a8e6e
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember to run `update-initramfs` after assembling the array as `md0`? if not, try stopping and re-assembling the array again and then doing so, i.e.

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md127
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

This should make the initial root filesystem 'aware' of the array at boot time

Comment: Sorry but it did not work. Half of it seems to work because the md0 file is present but `/dev/md127` is still present. There should be only one md* file which is `/dev/md0` array that holds my 3 drives. Using cat /proc/mdstat :
md0 : active raid0 sdc1[2] sdb3[1]
... 
md127 : active raid0 sdd1[0]

Comment: is that before or after rebooting?

Comment: It is what happend after I reboot

Comment: Hmmm... you may need to do `mdadm --remove /dev/md127` in between the `--stop` and the `--assemble` ?

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem,  mounting the md0 array in fstab fails with 'serious error encountered attempting to mount /mnt/md0' (or similar).  Frigged around with this for an hour, couldn't get it to work. Checked UUID, /proc/mdstat, mdadm.conf etc, all seems ok.

Added nobootwait option to fstab so it doens't lock up the boot process (headless server)

Looks like a race condition to me, because issuing the mount command manually after boot works fine.

Workaround that works for me:

edit rc.local, add following line before exit 0

sleep 10 && mount -t auto /dev/md0 /mnt/md0

Sideeffect is that the mount appears 10 seconds later, but I can live with that.  Without the sleep command, it didn't work.

Hope this helps someone.